# Проблема с геокодированием при получении адреса с csv файла через pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding

Есть список адресов(.csv) для которых нужно вытащить координаты
Скрипт выглядит следующим образом

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Arcgis\TATARS.CSV',delimiter=';')
for da in df.address:
    r = requests.get('http://search.maps.sputnik.ru/search/addr?q=da')
    data = (r.json()['result']['address'][0]['features'][0]['geometry']['geometries'][0]['coordinates'])
    print (data)
```

При запуске выдаёт следующее
`[-14.900021, 12.100035]` неправильные данные

Если вместо `da` вставлять адрес то выгрузка работает нормально

```
r = requests.get('http://search.maps.sputnik.ru/search/addr?q=Респ. Татарстан, р-н. Агрызский, г. Агрыз, ул. Азиатская, д. 47')
```

Выдаёт
`[52.9944, 56.511395]`

Проверил

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Arcgis\TATARS.CSV',delimiter=';')
print (df.address[1])
```

Выдаёт правильный адрес Респ. Татарстан, р-н. Агрызский, г. Агрыз, ул. Азиатская, д. 47

В чем может быть косяк ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Arcgis\TATARS.CSV',delimiter=';')
for da in df.address:
    r = requests.get('http://search.maps.sputnik.ru/search/addr?q='da)
    data = (r.json()['result']['address'][0]['features'][0]['geometry']['geometries'][0]['coordinates'])
    print (data)
```